# $q$-expansion of Modular forms

Tags: polynomials, elliptic-curves, modular-forms

I am trying to compute the $q$-expansion of $g\theta_2$ and $g\theta_4$, the $q$-expansion of modular forms of weight $3/2$ and level $128$ and trivial character and character $\chi_8$ respectively.

We have
$$g=q\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\big(1-q^{8n}\big)\big(1-q^{16n}\big),\quad \theta_t=\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}q^{tn^2}.$$

I would like to know the following:

- Are there formulas to find the coefficient of $q^d$ for any $d$?
- Is there a computer program to find it? (I should think so.)

I appreciate any help, or references to resources where I can find the answer. Thanks!

**EDIT**: I know the first few terms of $g\theta_2$: 
$$g\theta_2=q+2q^3+q^9-2q^{11}-4q^{17}-2q^{19}-3q^{25}+4q^{33}-4q^{35}+\dots$$

Comment: Often it helps to work out the initial terms and then consult the [OEIS](http://oeis.org).

Comment: @ccorn Hi ccorn, thanks for replying, but OEIS was not able to recognise the sequence above (see my edit). {1,2,1,-2,-4,-2,-3,4,-4}

Comment: Mind the exponents. Pad with zeros, at least for the odd exponents that are zero.

Comment: With padding (except for even exponents) you easily find [A034950](http://oeis.org/A034950), for example.

Comment: @ccorn of course you are right. So sorry for the lapse. :) But why pad only odd exponents though?

Comment: From the definitions of $g$ and $\theta_t$ you gave, it is obvious that $g\theta_t$ is odd in $q$ for even $t$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, it often helps to work out the initial terms and then consult the [OEIS](http://oeis.org). In your case,

1. [A034950](http://oeis.org/A034950) for $g\theta_2$, odd-indexed coefficients,
2. [A080966](http://oeis.org/A080966) for $g\theta_4$, coefficients with index $\equiv1\pmod{4}$

are relevant.
Among other things, you can find

1. recipes for computation e.g. with [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), usually by expanding products and quotients of the Dedekind eta function,
2. via the crossrefs: additive decompositions in terms of representation counts
   that are related to Tunnell's criterion for congruent numbers.

I suppose you know the latter because the notation used in your question matches the notation in [Tunnell's 1983 paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01389327).

Comment: That is right. I came about this via Tunnell's paper. Thanks ccorn!